# Is there any way to get solution file if we have source file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, decompiling

I published vb.net project and decompiled using justdecompile tool(dll file) and received source file is there any way to get solution file from that?

Comment: You've decompiled a compiled exe, your "source file" isn't the original source file, it's a reconstruction, including any compiler optimisations.  What you have bears only slightl resemblance to the the original .vb files and .sln.  So, no.

Comment: Just create a new solution and add all the vb files to it. I'm not sure what more you expect.

Comment: The solution file is just a way of logically arranging your projects in Visual Studio. It has nothing to do with what gets compiled. So no, you can't. Just create a new one, it's trivial. You probably need a new project file as well.

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: @MrLister there shows an error in gobal.asax and default.aspx file